# Retrieve the app push token from the device automatically in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Is it possible to get a device token (push token) automatically or without registering for push notification in iOS Swift?

Currently, we are getting device token while registering for push notifications:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No its not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. We can not retrieve the app push token from the device automatically or without registering for push notification in swift iOS